# Is this a valid x86 assembly instruction?

Tags: exception, binary, x86

I just downloaded the latest version of SmartMusic (http://www.smartmusic.com) and tried running it for the first time.
The thing is, there is an unhandled Win32 exception at the splash screen.
Being a geek/hacker (in the original sense of the word) I of course wanted to find out why things were that way, so I opened my Visual Studio debugger to take a look at the assembly and run it under a debugger.
The unhandled exception is an 'Illegal Instruction' and the instruction that is tripping it up is:
`cvtdq2ps    xmm0,xmm0`
Now, I don't really know much assembly, but this looks like a valid instruction to me ([here](http://siyobik.info/main/reference/instruction/CVTDQ2PS) is some information on it) so I was wondering if anyone knows how this is wrong and how (if possible) to fix it.
(i would rather fix something and just get it over with than spend an hour on the phone with tech support and just get "we'll have somebody look at it thanks for calling have a nice day `*`click`*`")
By the way, I have tried reinstalling it, so it's not that :)

here's the code before and after the exception

```
je          004DBAEA  
mov         edx,dword ptr [esp+8]  
push        edx  
call        007806A0  
mov         eax,dword ptr [esi+4]  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax+3EF0h]  
test        ecx,ecx  
je          004DBAFC  
call        007506A0  
mov         eax,dword ptr [esi+1CCh]  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [esi+4]  
mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx]  
push        eax  
mov         eax,dword ptr [edx+218h]  
call        eax  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [esi+4]  
mov         edx,dword ptr [ecx]  
movd        xmm0,dword ptr [esi+1B8h]  
mov         eax,dword ptr [edx+26Ch]  
push        ecx  
cvtdq2ps    xmm0,xmm0   ; this is the instruction it chokes on
movss       dword ptr [esp],xmm0  
call        eax  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [esi+4]  
movss       xmm0,dword ptr [esi+1ACh]  
movss       dword ptr [ecx+4ACh],xmm0  
xor         eax,eax  
cmp         dword ptr [esi+1B0h],eax  
setne       al  
cmp         eax,1  
mov         dword ptr [esi+1B0h],eax  
mov         eax,dword ptr [esi+4]  
sete        dl  
mov         byte ptr [eax+0ED2h],dl  
mov         edx,dword ptr [esi+4]  
xor         eax,eax  
cmp         dword ptr [esi+1B4h],eax  
setne       al  
cmp         eax,1
```

Comment: You want us to debug a program given a single line of assembly?

Comment: if you want, i'll post the first ~20 lines before and after it. this is a huge program (the exception is being thrown from line 0x004DBB24) so i can't post the whole thing. Mainly I was wondering if this instruction is legal

Comment: Does the `cvtdq2ps` command allow the input and output operand to refer to the same register?

Comment: @aroth: yes, `cvtdq2ps` can operate in place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you running on a very old machine (pre-2005 or so)? `cvtdq2ps` requires SSE2; it's hard for me to imagine that anyone is still using hardware that lacks SSE2 support, but it is possible.

**Edit**: yes, this is the issue.  The Athlon XP line has SSE, but not SSE2, which is the cause of the illegal instruction.  Time to modernize, I guess.  There's an increasingly large amount of software that requires SSE2 and SSE3.

Comment: I don't remember when I got this box, but it might be that old... It has an AMD Athlon XP 2800+ processor, if that's what you're talking about

Comment: @Nate Koppenhaver: yes, that's the issue.  Athlon XP does not support SSE2.

Comment: ok thanks! one more reason for my parents to let me buy a new Windows box ;)

Answer (score 0):

All variants why can this one generate an exc are listed on the page you'd linked. SIGILL is `#UD`:

> **#UD**    If an unmasked SIMD floating-point exception and CR4.OSXM MEXCPT[bit 10] = 0. If CR0.EM[bit 2] = 1. If CR4.OSFXSR[bit 9] = 0. If CPUID.01H:EDX.SSE2[bit 26] = 0. If the LOCK prefix is used.

Additional possible reason is when processor can't decode the instruction (has no support of SSE2; Pentium3 or AMD before 2003). Better manual lists this: http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc48.htm

> `#UD` - If an unmasked SIMD floating-point exception and OSXMMEXCPT in CR4 is 0. If EM in CR0 is set. If OSFXSR in CR4 is 0. If CPUID feature flag SSE2 is 0.